# What is the use of udevadm settle?

Tags: linux, udev

I have seen the of using udevadm settle command. What is the use of such a command in init scripts?

Answer (score 25):

After the kernel boots, `udevd` is used to create device nodes for all detected devices. That is a relatively time consuming task that *has* to be completed for the boot process to continue, otherwise there is a risk of services failing due to missing device nodes.

`udevadm settle` waits for `udevd` to process the device creation events for all hardware devices, thus ensuring that any device nodes have been created successfully before proceeding.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for… For the longest time, I’ve been trying to figure out how to cause `udevadm trigger` to block so that the script doesn’t get ahead and try to proceed before the devices are ready.